# How to make a resizable UserFrom?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I do not know how to make the simplest in the world resizable UserForm. What I have seen on different forum threads are terrible behemots (huge as the Universe libraries doing too much). But I need a simple, one stroke solution and I hope it exists. At this moment I have this code:

```
Dim myForm As UserForm1
Set myForm = New UserForm1
myForm.Caption = "Attributes"
myForm.Show
```

And I have `UserForm_Initialize()` which does some extra work. What is horrible (unreasonable?) is that by default a form is not resizable.

Comment: Plus one for properly instantiating the form! So what do you mean by re-sizable? You mean the user can drag the edges to whatever size they like and the controls will magically re-flow like in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Exactly!.............

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple guide on how to make a userform drag and re-sizable.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/558649-userform-movable-resizable.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is transcribed solution from

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/resize-a-userform.485489/

I have tested it and it works

First add these declaration to your header

```
'Declaration for form resize
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetLastError Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwErrCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
```

Add this sub to your form

```
Private Sub MakeFormResizable()

'Written: August 02, 2010
'Author:  Leith Ross
'Summary: Makes the UserForm resizable by dragging one of the sides. Place a call
'         to the macro MakeFormResizable in the UserForm'
'from  https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/resize-a-userform.485489/

  Dim lStyle As Long
  Dim hWnd As Long
  Dim RetVal
  
  Const WS_THICKFRAME = &H40000
  Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16)
  
    hWnd = GetActiveWindow
  
    'Get the basic window style
     lStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) Or WS_THICKFRAME
     
    'Set the basic window styles
     RetVal = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle)
    
    'Clear any previous API error codes
     SetLastError 0
    
    'Did the style change?
     If RetVal = 0 Then MsgBox "Unable to make UserForm Resizable."
     
End Sub
```

And finally call this sub from your Userform_Activate

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    MakeFormResizable
End Sub
```

Comment: is there a version that works for 64 bit?

Comment: @cheese10234 Use IntPtr for the hWnd instead of long.